# ASP.NET Core enrich IIdentity with custom profile

Tags: asp.net-core, identity, iprincipal

I am using Azure AD to authorize and authenticate the users.
All users have a profile in the database.

I would like on login to always "merge" the Azure user with my database user.

This is the code I am using to setup authentication in my web api.

```
public static partial class ServiceCollectionExtensions
{
    public static IServiceCollection AddBearerAuthentication(this IServiceCollection services,
        OpenIdConnectOptions openIdConnectOptions)
    {
    #if DEBUG
        IdentityModelEventSource.ShowPII = true;
    #endif

        services
            .AddAuthentication("Bearer")
            .AddJwtBearer("Bearer", o =>
            {
                o.Authority = openIdConnectOptions.Authority;
                o.TokenValidationParameters.ValidIssuer = openIdConnectOptions.ValidIssuer;
                o.TokenValidationParameters.ValidAudiences = openIdConnectOptions.ValidAudiences;
            });

        return services;
    }
}
```

Can someone point me in the right direction?
Right now I am loading the user in all of my controllers, not pretty at all.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what do you mean by "merge" the user. But if it's just some logic you want to run for every incoming http request, you could just add a custom middleware

```cs
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    var user = await context.RequestServices
                            .GetRequiredService<DatabaseContext>()
                            .Users
                            .Where(....)
                            .SingleOrDefaultAsync();
    ...
    await next(context);
});
```

Alternatively, if you want to couple your code with the authentication process very much, you could use the callback from `JwtBearerOptions`

```cs
.AddJwtBearer("Bearer", o =>
{
    ...
    o.Events.OnTokenValidated = async context =>
    {
        var user = await context.HttpContext
                                .RequestServices
                                .GetRequiredService....
        ...
    };
}
```

But personally, I think both approaches are bad. Going to the DB to get the user's credentials with every request is bad for performance. Also, it kinda defies the whole point of the JWT, which was designed specifically to not do that. The token should already contain all the claims inside. If it doesn't, I would suggest reconfiguring azure AD, or switch to self-issued tokens.

Comment: First thanks for the answer. We have many application that has some data about the user, call it preferences. I would like to "merge" that data with the User you have on the thread when you work with controllers in Asp.Net core web api

Comment: You can't merge user identity, they are read-only, but you can add a new one ```context.User.AddIdentity(...)```.

Comment: I know. I need to create a custom Identity. I need to rephrase my question  I put merge in quotes because I know that you can not merge it. I just need help with extending the object I have after authentication from Azure AD